# JSON no value for "column" but JSON data is available

Tags: java, android, json

I'm facing an issue whereas I retrieve JSON data from my server to then display it in a recyclerview in Android. The data is available as if I log it it does display as follows:

```
D/------>: onSuccess: {"{\"vtmtransaction\":\"f53fa6ba-ccbf-4aa0-b948-b4305f279cfd\",\"vtmowner\":\"a8dd0bd7-1d6f-4262-ab66-14492ce183ac\",\"vtmoriginname\":\"Dar es Salaam\",\"vtmdestinationname\":\"Arusha\",\"vtmpickupdate\":\"2019-05-26T22:00:00.000Z\",\"vtmpickuptime\":\"08:30:00\",\"vtmvehicletype\":1,\"vtmmodel\":\"Land cruisera\",\"vtmfueltype\":1,\"vtmenginenumber\":\"sdasda\",\"vtmchassisnumber\":\"sdasd\",\"vtmenginecapacity\":2000,\"vtminsurance\":false,\"vtminsurancetype\":null,\"vtmclearingandforwarding\":false,\"vtmvehicleservice\":false,\"vtmvehicleservicetype\":null,\"vtmvehiclemake\":1,\"vtmorigincountry\":\"Tanzania\",\"vtmdestinationcountry\":\"Tanzania\",\"vtmbookedwhen\":\"2019-05-26T22:00:00.000Z\",\"vtmorigincoords\":\"0101000020E6100000FC694881AA9A43404C6BD3D85E2B1BC0\",\"vtmdestinationcoords\":\"0101000020E610000010F4064E6C5742400AEF17586C180BC0\"}":{"vtmtransaction":"f53fa6ba-ccbf-4aa0-b948-b4305f279cfd","vtmowner":"a8dd0bd7-1d6f-4262-ab66-14492ce183ac","vtmoriginname":"Dar es Salaam","vtmdestinationname":"Arusha","vtmpickupdate":"2019-05-26T22:00:00.000Z","vtmpickuptime":"08:30:00","vtmvehicletype":1,"vtmmodel":"Land cruisera","vtmfueltype":1,"vtmenginenumber":"sdasda","vtmchassisnumber":"sdasd","vtmenginecapacity":2000,"vtminsurance":false,"vtminsurancetype":null,"vtmclearingandforwarding":false,"vtmvehicleservice":false,"vtmvehicleservicetype":null,"vtmvehiclemake":1,"vtmorigincountry":"Tanzania","vtmdestinationcountry":"Tanzania","vtmbookedwhen":"2019-05-26T22:00:00.000Z","vtmorigincoords":"0101000020E6100000FC694881AA9A43404C6BD3D85E2B1BC0","vtmdestinationcoords":"0101000020E610000010F4064E6C5742400AEF17586C180BC0"}}
```

Once I receive the JSONArray, I convert it to a JSONObject as I do not want to work with indexes but the column names directly from the data but I always get the following error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for vtmoriginname
```

This is the relevant part in the fragment that retrieves the data with AsyncHttpRequest and fires the process on completion of the request. The data comes from node.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mybookings = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mybookings, container, false);
        preferences = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("mykago-cars", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        t = new Tools(getActivity().getApplication(), getContext(), getActivity());
        prgBookings = mybookings.findViewById(R.id.prgBookings);
        final RecyclerView recyclerViewMyBookings = mybookings.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMyBookings);

        AsyncHttpRequest.client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(2, 5000);
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("uuid", preferences.getString("myUUID", ""));
        AsyncHttpRequest.get("my_bookings", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                t.myDialog(R.string.dataError, R.string.databaseDataNotAvailable, true, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                prgBookings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                // Covert the JSONArray to a JSONObject so we can reference the columns by name and not index. Makes things easier and avoids mistakes..
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.toJSONObject(response);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + jsonObject);
                    // Loop through response and add all items to the mybooking list
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                        MyBookings_Data myBookings_data = new MyBookings_Data();
                        try {
                            myBookings_data.setMbdorigin(jsonObject.getString("vtmoriginname"));
                            myBookings_data.setMbddestination(jsonObject.getString("vtmdestinationname"));
                            myBookings_data.setMbdpickupdate(jsonObject.getString("vtmpickupdate"));
                            myBookings_data.setMbdpickuptime(jsonObject.getString("vtmpickuptime"));
                            myBookings_data.setMdbdate(jsonObject.getString("vtmbookedwhen"));
                            myBookings_data_list.add(myBookings_data);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    MyBookingsRecyclerViewAdapter myBookingsRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyBookingsRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), myBookings_data_list);
                    recyclerViewMyBookings.setAdapter(myBookingsRecyclerViewAdapter);
                    recyclerViewMyBookings.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return mybookings;
    }
```

Comment: Your response is not an array to loop through

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `for loop` and try again because in your `json` response `JsonArray` not available.
So don't need to use `for loop`

Comment: Thanks I removed the for loop but with no effect. Still giving the same error

Comment: Something is not so correct in your JSON, searched for vtmoriginname and got 2 occurences, 1 is escaped on " and another is not. Which line specifically is throwing the exception